# How to connect to remote SQL Server for login validation in flask

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a flask project where I need to connect to a remote SQL Server for validating login credentials and session management. Being new to the flask environment, I am not able to work my head around sqlalchemy with SQL Server. Also, how to user `LoginManager()` for maintaining login sessions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! First try to approach the problem and if you're failing with a specific issue, post the code that didn't work for you and explain the problem. Here is a reference on [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The only difference there is between working with a local database vs a hosted one is the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI.

Now if that database is read only and already have defined tables, then it's another problem, but I can't deduct that from your question.

Comment: I tried defining the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI in the app, and it worked. The main concern for me now is that whether I should perform db migrate or not?